# StrongLoop API Explorer Not Working With `apic strongloop` Scaffolding / Generator

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, apiconnect

I am learning LoopBack (aka Strongloop). When I go to https://strongloop.com/ it tells me to install `npm install -g apiconnect`. So, I'm learning LoopBack with the scaffolding from `apic loopback`

Once I get a starter project going with `apic loopback`, and add a model with `apic create --type model`, it looks like my definitions where my Swagger is defined is automatically updated (./definitions/server.yaml). As a result, I am able to explore those APIs when I run `apic edit`.

However, when I edit a model to extend my API, as demonstrated in the LoopBack documentation (https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Extend+your+API), I don't see the updated API documentation... but from the documentation that looks like the "Explorer" should pick up the new API endpoint.

What am I missing here? Is there a swagger command that I'm supposed to run when I create manual API extensions? Or perhaps it's some kind of magic comments in the code?

Bottom line: how do I get my loopback API customizations / extensions to show up in the Explorer when I'm using `apic` put out by IBM? Do I have to use `apic create --type api`? Is there a way to get the explorer to pick up my changes as I customize my API? Exactly how magical is this thing?

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I solved my problem:

(1) I installed the `loopback-component-explorer` package:

```
npm install loopback-component-explorer --save-dev
```

(2) I added a ./server/component-config.json file that contains the following:

```
{
    "loopback-component-explorer": {
        "mountPath": "/explorer"
    }
}
```

(3) Instead of viewing my documentation through `apic edit`, I can now view it at `http://0.0.0.0:3000/explorer`. Unlike the `apic edit` explorer, this one picks up the changes I make dynamically.

Apparently, when you setup your project with `slc loopback` you get this baked into the scaffolding, but because IBM really wants you to use their API Connect designer, they leave the StrongLoop API Explorer out when you use `apic loopback` to setup your project. Unfortunately, the API Connect Explorer does not appear to pickup API changes that are done programatically.

Comment: "Unfortunately, the API Connect Explorer does not appear to pickup API changes that are done programatically"...shouldn't it pick up the changes if you restart the server?

Comment: @AlexanderMills I use nodeMon to rebuild my loopback project as I make changes (I transpile from TypeScript, so it's also helps with that). If I add or change something that I want reflected in the explorer, I just refresh that browser window and it's up to date. Many of my apis are programmatically defined and it all seems to work for me.